# Azure Storage Explorer (In browser) fails in Sweden datacenter

Tags: azure-storage

I have the storage account: twitterdata02switzerland where I'm no longer able to access the data I have stored there using the web browser nor Storage Explorer, and I receive the error "The request is not authorized to perform the operation using this permission."

I am logged in using the Microsoft account I used to create this Storage account and it is no longer visible to me.

[image: twitterdata02switzerland error]

Comment: Can you please check if the storage account is behind a firewall? Also, please tell us about the details of this storage account (kind etc.).

Comment: @GauravMantri This is a standard storage account, not behind a firewall, and is a very simple deployment. No VPN, No Firewall

Answer (score 0):

Looks you didn't have a correct RBAC role in your storage account, navigate to the `Access Control (IAM)` of your storage account in the portal -> add an RBAC role e.g. `Owner`, `Contributor`, `Storage Account Contributor` to your user account like below.

[image]